# Ionic copyFile error code 5, ENCODING_ERR

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I'm wondering, what is the problem.
`this.file` - is the imported ionic native File plugin.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

  constructor(
    ...
    private file: File,
    ...) {
    super();
  }
```

My code:

```
  // Copy the image to to the application storage directory
  private copyFileToLocalDir(imagePath, newFileName) {
    // Special handling for Android library
    const imageDir = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    const fileName = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    console.log('imagePath:');
    console.log(imagePath);
    console.log('imageDir:');
    console.log(imageDir);
    console.log('fileName:');
    console.log(fileName);
    console.log('this.file.dataDirectory:');
    console.log(this.file.dataDirectory);
    console.log('newFileName:');
    console.log(newFileName);

    this.file
      .copyFile(imageDir, fileName, this.file.dataDirectory, newFileName)
      .then(
        () => {
          this.uploadImage(newFileName);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log('File save error:');
          console.log(err);
          this.notificationService.errorMessage('Ошибка сохранения файла');
        }
      );
  }
```

The otput:

```
imagePath:
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1532935809457.jpg
imageDir:
1532935809457.jpg
fileName:
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/
this.file.dataDirectory:
file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/
newFileName:
1532935810087.jpg
File save error:
FileError
code: 5
message: "ENCODING_ERR"
```

The code was working before my big refactoring and before ionic CLI update. I were using Ionic v3.2.0 before, now it is v4.0.1

What is the problem?

Answer (score -3):

I have found the problem.
SO SAID, that noone saw it here...

```
imageDir:
1532935809457.jpg
fileName:
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/
```

I inadvertently switched the names of the variables, when I were refactoring the code.